# IO Mapping in Codesys

Tags: sensors, plc, codesys, actuator

I am using a ifm AC1421 PLC. I am using a ifm AC2218 D/A module to operate the actuators i.e. proportional valves. A/D module AC2517 ifm is used to get the data from pressure sensors.

I wanted to have an idea on how is the I/O mapping done in Codesys i.e. at what address do i need to define them.

I have attached an image which shows the current assigned variables.

Say for ex. I have assigned my PV1 at %QW47 and PV2 at %QW50.

Can I not assign PV2 at %QW48 or %QW49?
If i assign them the PV2 doesn't get operated

Similar goes with the Sensors I have assigned at %IW32,33 and 34. Can i not assign them at %IW37,38 or 39?

[Actuators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKlvF.png)
[Sensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyp9h.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, unless you need to know the exact memory address of those inputs/variables elsewhere in your code, you shouldn't really pay attention to the address. What you should care about are the Channels. Where you should assign/map your variables to will depend on what channel your input is wired to.